# "The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)" when using "Get Metadata" activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: filter, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, metadata

I want to get a list of files in a Container, Azure Blob Storage using "Get Metadata" activity in Azure Data Factory.

There are many files in the container around 10,000,000 files (zip files).

The activity fails getting the below error:

```
The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)
```

Is there any way that I can apply a filter in this activity to limit the output size?

Or if there is any other solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> "The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)"

***The cause of error is the folder or container from where you are getting the Child items contain more than 5000 child items and the size of output is more than 4MB.***

**To Resolve this issue, you Can create a file with bunch of 5000 filenames to iterate overusing dataflow (if you have non-binary file type).**

1. create a data flow and add your source data set with the container.
   [image]
   and source setting as wildcards and add file paths.
   [image]
   It will add **filespath** column with respective file paths. Then use aggregate transformation to group by **filepath** column and create **filepaths** all column as below:
   [image]
   [image]
   Then add sink dataset with the folder name **bunchall** in sink transformation
   [image]
   sink settings as below for partition files
   [image]
   Add partition on data to get files with 4500 filenames in each files.
   [image]

**Output:**
[image]

2. Then after this using same sink dataset you will get all files in that folder in get metadata activity.
   [image]
3. Then pass this output to Foreach loop and then under foreach look take lookup activity to get file names in partitioned files.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write the answer. The stored files are zip files.